# Fix intersecting faces in blender

Tags: modifiers

I have a complicated geometry with some really small (not very visible) self-intersecting faces to fix, like below:

[image]

I have tried to use the `shrinkwrap` modifier and wrapped a fine-meshed cube on its surface. However, even though the cube is very finely meshed, the approximation is still not good:

[image]

I can use `remesh` modifier to fix the self-intersecting faces, but it requires an astronomical amount of vertices (deep octree) to maintain the geometry.

Could anyone please help with some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to automatically fix overlapping faces, I guess, and even a function hiding all but intersecting faces won't help, since most times you need to see the rest of the mesh to fix those errors, but since you have just a few of intersecting faces, to better find/fix them manually, you could hide large parts of geometry (Hkey), allowing better visualization to smaller corners. Then fix, unhide (ALT+Hkey) and repeat.

Comment: You can use the remesh modifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What was the step that introduced this geometry problems? In general it's better to avoid geometry problems at all than to try to fix it. So i would suggest to have an eye at your workflow.

At this point i would retopology such a problematic mesh by hand now. No algorithm can know which vertices to keep and which not. So there is imho at this stage no way around manual work.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less my process for cleaning up intersecting faces.

1. Using the 3D printing plugin, detect intersecting faces.
2. Make manifold, also 3D printing plugin.
3. Triangulate all intersecting faces.
4. Recalculate, hopefully the count has gone down. It could have gone up.
5. Shrink/fatten a tiny amount.
6. Recalculate, undo unless count went down considerably.
7. Smooth vertices a tiny amount unless intersections are hard surface geometry. This can obviously distort geometry in weird ways.
8. Repeat and combine.
9. Manual work using merge vertices, rotate edges, collapse edges, make faces (from several) etc.

This way above preserves geometry the best. You can also use the modifiers Remesh (with lots and lots of detail) and then Decimate. It will probably smooth your geometry a little bit. But it can be significantly faster (cleaning hundreds of intersections takes time).

I have written a tiny plugin that, after calculating intersections, focus on one of the problems.

https://github.com/markuskruse/blender-addon-focus-island

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

1. Switch to edit mode
2. Select all vertices
3. Select `Remove Doubles`

Comment: This is a bad idea because it can join geometry in very weird ways, making it even worse.